# How do you copy an Android Studio/Mercurial project from Windows to MAC?

Tags: android-studio, mercurial, tortoisehg

I'm getting myself into a bit of a tiz here.

I want to copy an Android Studio development project onto an Apple Macbook for remote working. Simple. (?)

The project uses Mercurial for code control. I have only placed the actual `src` files (including 'build.gradle' and the manifest etc.)  under code control (adding `.idea`, `build`, `.gradle` et al seemed a bit over the top).

I have tried copying the PROJECT file lock, stock and barrel across to the Mac, but since this is not a proper "clone" of the Mercurial repo, I am worried that merging will not work properly and I'll damage both copies of the project.

I have tried 'cloning' the repository into an empty PROJECT directory on the Mac and then starting Android Studio, but this loaded revision 1 of the project with none of the build variants. Even upgrading to the latest version, the project won't build properly (probably because of the files that aren't under code control).

So... what is the simple way of cloning (for want of a better word) a project onto a different computer and then being able to use Mercurial to keep future code changes in sync?

Should I commit everything in the project directory into to Mercurial and try cloning and copying the repository again?

Or is there a smart way of setting up Mercurial correctly when I have copied the PROJECT directory?

Or is a moderator just going to tell me to f off and ask the Software Engineering lot? :)

Comment: Why do you think that omitting the configuration files oh how the build shall be done seems over the top? Why don't you simply copy the complete repo directory and add those to VCS which don't need to differ between your systems?

Comment: When I started the project I didn't believe that adding generated build files into code control was necessary. That may have been the wrong decision. I'm listening to advice here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I've got this working satisfactorily now. My solution was a hybrid between the two options. A bit of a hack, but I can now push and pull changes between the two repos which is what I wanted to achieve.

- I copied the complete PROJECT directory onto the Macbook
- I `cloned` the Mercurial repo to a separate temporary directory (using TortoiseHG).
- I deleted the `.hg` subdirectory that was copied onto the Macbook, and replaced it with the `.hg` from the temporary directory.
- I then updated the PROJECT directory from the Mercurial clone in order to get the repo in sync (again using TortoiseHG).

I don't believe this the the "correct" way of achieving a working copy of a Mercurial/Android Studio project but it's working for me.